# If $X⊂\operatorname{int}A$, so $∂X=Df$ where $Df$ is set of descontinuity points of the indicator function of $X$

Tags: real-analysis

Today, I would like to do a presentation at my university about sets and the Jordan Measure. So, I need to formalize my notes.

The problem is:

> If $X\subset\operatorname{int} A$, then $\partial X = Df$.

Can anyone help to formalize this proof?

Recall that:

1) $Df$ is the set of discontinuity points of the indicator function for $X$, given by $f: A\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x\in X$ and $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\notin X$.

2) If $x$ is on the boundary $\partial X$, so that every neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $X$ and $\Bbb R^n\setminus X$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \partial X$. Then each neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $X$ and points of $\mathbb R^n \setminus X$. Hence there are sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$ and $(y_n)$ in $A \setminus X$ with $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to x$.

It follows that $f(x_n)=1$ for all $n$ and $f(y_n)=0$ for all $n$.

Consequence: $\lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) \ne \lim_{n \to \infty}f(y_n)$ and therefore $x \in D_f$.

It is now your turn to show that $x \in D_f$ implies $x \in \partial X$.

Comment: Let me try, if x ∈ Df, so: 1) x ∉ int X, because f is constant, so f is continuous in int X 2) x ∉ int (A - X) because f is constant in int(A-X), so f is continuous in int (A-X). So, for 1) and 2) -> x ∈ ∂X, hence we can write R=int X ∪ Int (R−X) ∪ ∂X

Answer (score 0):

A topological proof(both directions):

Being on the boundary $\partial X$ means any neighborhood of $x$ maps to the entire discrete topology $\{0, 1\}$.

This is equivalent to saying the image of any neigborhood of $x$ strictly contains $f(x)$. $f(x)$ is the only nontrivial open set containing $f(x)$. Thus it equivalent to say every nontrivial open set containing $f(x)$(which is just $f(x)$) does not contain the image of any neighborhood of $x$(which is just $\{0, 1\}$).

But that means $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p\in \partial X=\overline X \cap \overline {X^c}$ then every nbhd of $p$ contains a member of $f^{-1}\{0\}=X$ and a member of $f^{-1}\{1\}=X^c.$

So  if $p\in X\cap \partial X$ then $f$ cannot map any  nbhd of $p$  into $(1/2,1]=(1/2,f(p)] .$

And if $p\in X^c\cap \partial X$ then $f$ cannot map any nbhd of $p$  into $[0,1/2)=[f(p),1/2).$

Meanwhile, $f$ is constant on each of the open sets int($X$) and int($X^c$), and the whole space is $(\partial X)\;\cup\; $(int $(X))\;\cup \;($int($X^c)).$